# Text in Pdf file out of the right margin, and strange chacarters - libreoffice draw

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, pdf

When I open a Pdf file in libreoffice Draw, the text exceeds the right margin, and strange characters appear in the text. How can I fix it?

Original (opened with document viewer):

[image]

Opened with libreoffice draw:

[image]

Comment: I get this too sometimes, and what's happening is that Draw does not have the exact font the original document was authored with, so it uses a default which is wider. Can you try selecting all and changing the font to a narrower one as a workaround? I don't have an easy fix so posting this suggestion as a comment.

Comment: Hello @TomBrossman thank you for your suggestion; I tried to select all and change the font; the situation is better, but there are still overlapped text

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Are you still having this problem? Can you provide a link to a sample `pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem and this is how I solved it:

1. You have to find what font is used in the pdf file. On KDE you can find it opening the pdf file with Okular.
2. Once in Okular you can see the font has been used under File - Properties (shortcut Alt+Return).
3. Now you have to download the font identified from Internet. Ask Google for the font name.
4. The file must contain a directory called like the font that must copy in /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ (if the font is a true type font).

I hope it works for you.